# How to set a color for all pages in php?

Tags: php, background-color

How can you set the background colors for all pages inside of a php session? and then recall it on each page? like right now im using:

```
include('background.php')
```

but im only using that for the basic pages, i have a whole page setup for other colors to change to, but i dont want to write 150 pages for all the colors for the whole site, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you can't do it via CSS?

Comment: im not quite sure how to do css :P i know how to do php coding a lot more XD

Comment: PHP is definitely not what you should be using. Use CSS. If you don't know CSS, look for resources about it and learn the basics. It won't take you more than a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including a php file, you should try something like this.

Every time you want to modify the background color, add a class to the body.

```
<?php
  $bodyClass = '';

  if (YOUR CONDITION)
     $bodyClass = 'darkBackground';
?>

<body class="<?php echo $bodyClass; ?>">
...
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
body.darkBackground {background-color: black}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CSS. It's not the PHP stuff.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in details?

Comment: my problem is that i want users to be able to change their background colors, i have the different codes for colors programmed already, i just need to know that when users click on the link that ALL pages on my site will change to that color, and not just the first page

Comment: Save color code in database and always add it to $_SESSION data when user log in (or smth like this).